# Is there such thing as default password strength rules/constrains in Postge?

Tags: postgresql, passwords

I am creating a password generator for Postgresql users. I cannot find out anything in the official docs, regarding the rules for the password quality.

Numerous articles and questions circle around `passwordcheck` [module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/passwordcheck.html)

But it is not enabled by default, why?

And is there default rule for password strength in Postgre?

Comment: There is no password strength check in the core Postgresql. `passwordcheck` is a contrib module/extension, it is not loaded by default. Assuming you have the -contrib modules installed/complied you can load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to enable the `passwordcheck` module.

The main reason why it is not enabled by default is its limited usefulness: it is only effective for passwords sent to the server in clear text, which is bad security practice to begin with. If you use a more secure method like `psql`'s `\password`, the server never sees the clear text password and consequently cannot check it.

The deep reason why there are no more advanced password checks is that the PostgreSQL community deems passwords in the database second-rate security. For serious security requirements, use central identity management and authenticate with Kerberos or one of the other authentication methods. Then have your password strength checks in the identity management system, which specializes in this area.

Comment: Not seeing that community opinion here [Authentication Methods](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-methods.html).

Comment: It's not an outspoken, official opinion, and I am sure people will disagree, but some of it transpired at the time I wrote passwordcheck. You could read up the thread on -hackers.